# How to show the gallery title in the image overlay in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress 4.2.2 with use of enfold theme. I need to show the gallery title in the image overlay options. Right now i am using the WP Easy Gallery plugin. In that i have customized the overaly options. But i cant show the title in the overlay of image. The title showing in under the image and image mouse over also. Because i have created this page using WordPress pages. In which function/page i need to write code for this. Below i have added my current gallery image. And after that i have shown what i need exactly for overlay title. Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i'm right enfold comes with Layer Slider, which provide such functionality. It would be a better choice to use it to do what you try to achieve.

Comment: Yes... else can you share the link please?

Comment: And also the layer slider provide the popup with more images. Because i need both in one option. first overlay of the image and when i click on the image that need to show more images of that gallery. that i need to change from admin side.

Comment: This is my link, http://ef.efvoice.com/ef/?page_id=1719

Comment: Thanks guys for you support. Finally i make it with css options to fixed the overlay text.